# installing _imagingft

Tags: python, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: The _imagingft C module is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011705/python-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed)

It seem that some of my problems with working with fonts, are due to the luck of _imagingft module. how can I install it? what are the steps

Comment: Hm. A friend has Windows 7, and while Python + PIL are installed correctly, _imagingft.pyd is where it's supposed to be and in the sys.path directories, using ImageFont fails with something about assemblies in the interactive interpreter, and I wish I could help him, but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

It's created by building PIL with the FreeType development files in place.