# Trouble using PIL in Django app on Windows

Tags: python, django, xampp, python-imaging-library

I'm learning a little Django with the [Python Web Development with Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132356139) book.  All was going well until I tried to build the **photos** application which requires the PIL (Python Imaging Library).  When I try to add an image through the admin interface I receive an error message pasted below.

I am running Windows 7, Python 2.7, Django 1.3b1, and XAMPP 1.7.3 with the wsgi module successfully installed (at least I think so, since the rest of my Django experiments work fine).

Following the troubleshooting guide from the PIL site I have tried to import the PIL modules at the Python  prompt:

```
>>>import _imaging
>>>import Image
```

Both work fine, without displaying an error.  However, trying to run the Django admin app that uses PIL results in:

> ImportError at /admin/items/photo/add/
>   The _imaging C module is not installed
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://localhost:8888/photos/admin/items/photo/add/
>   Django Version: 1.3 beta 1 SVN-15679
>   Exception Type: ImportError
>   Exception Value:
>   The _imaging C module is not installed
>   Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in **getattr**, line 37
>   Python Executable:  C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
>   Python Version: 2.7.0
>   Python Path:
>   ['C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.10-py2.7.egg',
>    'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.4-py2.7.egg',
>    'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openglcontext_full-2.1.0a7-py2.7.egg',
>    'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ttfquery-1.0.4-py2.7.egg',
>    'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fonttools-2.3-py2.7-win32.egg',
>    'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydispatcher-2.0.2-py2.7.egg',
>    'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyside-1.0.0beta1qt471-py2.7-win32.egg',
>    'C:\code\ots',
>    'C:\lib\django',
>    'C:\code',
>    'C:\xampp',
>    'C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip',
>    'C:\Python27\Lib',
>    'C:\Python27\DLLs',
>    'C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk',
>    'C:\xampp\apache\bin',
>    'C:\Users\garethconner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages',
>    'C:\Python27',
>    'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages',
>    'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL',
>    'C:\lib\django\django',
>    'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32',
>    'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
>    'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
>    'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
>    'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.9.1-msw',
>    'C:\code']

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the PIL library on your python path?

Comment: Does the command lines work when ran from python manage.py shell? Does the pb occur when the site is served with python manage.py runserver?

Comment: @Exelian: Yes, it's hard to pick out in that dump, but it is on the python path.  On the command line, python can import the module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've answered this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011705/python-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed/4011715#4011715)

Just install pre-compiled binaries for Windows (for your python version) from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked perfectly.  Sorry that I missed your previous answer.  I searched on SO and found a bunch of suggestions that didn't work but somehow missed yours.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when the same installer (windows, Python2.7) downloaded from the official PIL site did not. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for this advice - I had already tried reinstalling from the official PIL site and probably wouldn't have tried reinstalling *again* from this link if you hadn't said this.  It seems the official PIL site's binaries are 32-bit only, even though it doesn't say that anywhere on their site.