# Reportlab can't find _imaging module using production server

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, reportlab

I'm trying to push a django app to the production server, but for some reason it fails and says:

> ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed

The weird part is that when I use the development server on the same machine, it works just fine.  PIL is installed, and I can import the _imaging module by hand in the shell.  The production server uses Apache.  Any ideas?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 111, in get_response
>       response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:/portal2\compliance\views.py", line 91, in show_statement
>       doc.build(Story, onFirstPage=firstPage, onLaterPages=otherPage)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 1117, in build
>       BaseDocTemplate.build(self,flowables, canvasmaker=canvasmaker)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 877, in build
>       self.clean_hanging()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 510, in clean_hanging
>       self.handle_flowable(self._hanging)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 757, in handle_flowable
>       f.apply(self)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 140, in apply
>       getattr(doc,arn)(*args)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 1093, in handle_pageBegin
>       self._handle_pageBegin()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 535, in handle_pageBegin
>       self.pageTemplate.onPage(self.canv,self)
>
> File "C:/portal2\compliance\views.py", line 55, in firstPage
>       canvas.drawImage(img,0,0,8.5*inch,11*inch)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfgen\canvas.py", line 857, in drawImage
>       imgObj = pdfdoc.PDFImageXObject(name, image, mask=mask)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 2094, in **init**
>       self.loadImageFromA85(src)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 2100, in loadImageFromA85
>       imagedata = map(string.strip,pdfutils.makeA85Image(source,IMG=IMG))
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfutils.py", line 34, in makeA85Image
>       raw = img.getRGBData()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 658, in getRGBData
>       annotateException('\nidentity=%s'%self.identity())
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 655, in getRGBData
>       self._data = im.tostring()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 532, in tostring
>       self.load()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 164, in load
>       self.load_prepare()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 231, in load_prepare
>       self.im = Image.core.new(self.mode, self.size)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 37, in **getattr**
>       raise ImportError("The _imaging C module is not installed")
>
> ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed
>   identity=[ImageReader@0x4517a30 filename='C:\portal2\pdf\Certification_fullframe.tif']
>      handle_pageBegin args=()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

[Trouble using PIL in Django app on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352968/trouble-using-pil-in-django-app-on-windows)

I had to install a version of PIL that was precompiled to work with mod-wsgi.

Answer (score 2):

PIL should be installed before library which uses it. I got similar problem with `libimaging` - PIL wasn't installed before libimaging so libimaging was compiled without it. Solution was uninstall libimaging and install it again with PIL already present in system.