# Unable to Install with easy_install or pip on mac

Tags: python, lxml, pip, easy-install, pycrypto

I'm trying to install lxml and pycrypto modules using easy_install (and pip) but getting error messages like

```
Running lxml-2.3.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-kGsWMh/lxml-2.3.4/egg-dist-tmp-Gjqy3f
Building lxml version 2.3.4.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.24
In file included from /usr/include/limits.h:63,
                 from /Developer/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.0.1/include/limits.h:10,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:19,
                 from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4:
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:540:4: error: #error Unknown architecture
In file included from /usr/include/limits.h:64,
                 from /Developer/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.0.1/include/limits.h:10,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:19,
                 from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4:
/usr/include/machine/limits.h:10:2: error: #error architecture not supported
In file included from /usr/include/sys/_types.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/_types.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:67,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:33,
                 from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4:
/usr/include/machine/_types.h:36:2: error: #error architecture not supported
In file included from /usr/include/_types.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:67,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:33,
                 from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4:
/usr/include/sys/_types.h:94: error: syntax error before ‘__darwin_blkcnt_t’
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:165640: error: syntax error before ‘val’
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:165645: error: syntax error before ‘val’
```

bla bla . . .

```
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:165645: error: syntax error before ‘val’

lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/f3/2q2x2p015kzgd4nbrn_qwykh0000gn/T//cc1pnrww.out

error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm getting similar syntax errors when I try to install pycrypto as well. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277124) but in vain. I tried setting up for python 2.6 and 2.7 environments using setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg and setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg but getting the same output.

I searched a lot online but cant find solution for this.

**EDIT:** I'm on OSX 10.7 on macbook pro 2010, and have XCode 4 and 3 installed

I'd args with replaced with the latest version while trying the commands in the link above.

```
python setup.py build --static-deps --libxml2-version=2.7.8  --libxslt-version=1.1.26 
sudo python setup.py install
```

I read on someother post and tried this as well

```
STATIC_DEPS=true sudo easy_install --allow-hosts=lxml.de,*.python.org lxml
```

**Solution:**

As @jdi suggested I did the following

```
$ brew install --use-llvm libxml2
$ brew install --use-llvm libxslt
```

Installed gcc from [link](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer), since I was still facing issues with option 1 and 2 suggested

Then, either this

```
$ export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
$ /usr/bin/python2.6 setup.py build
$ sudo /usr/bin/python2.6 setup.py install
```

Or this, will work

```
$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" easy_install-2.6 lxml
```

Same worked for pycrypto as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This right here is an indication that you are building it improperly: `/Developer/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10`, unless of course you are on an old powerpc machine.

Check the version of OSX you are running, and the commands you are using to build lxml. Chances are you might need to set `export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"` in your shell before building, in order to avoid it building with `ppc`. Not sure why you are getting an old arch.

Also, make sure you have the latest Xcode installed. And, if you are following that link you posted, word for word, make sure you are using the most recent versions of those packages and not the literal versions as that link is 3 years old.

If all else fails, install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and install it through that package manager.

**Update:** Options for lack of GCC 4.2 after XCode 4.2+ update

Pick one

1. Install gcc 4.2 using this simple guide:
   http://caiustheory.com/install-gcc-421-apple-build-56663-with-xcode-42
2. Use homebrew to install it:

   `brew tap homebrew/dupes`
   `brew install homebrew/dupes/apple-gcc42`
3. Completely ignore gcc and use llvm with brew

   `brew install --use-llvm libxml2`

Comment: I've updated the post to answer your questions. I'm still not sure why easy_install doesnt work since ideally i'm not required to configure anything if I used easy_install right

Comment: @rajivvishwa: remove xcode 3, and make sure xcode 4 is updated to the latest. You obviously have an architecture issue if its trying to build ppc. Also, make sure in the latest xcode4 you go into the prefs and have it install the command line tools. Im betting you didn't update the command line tools and its still building with xcode 3 tools.

Comment: As suggested, I removed Xcode 3 completely and installed the latest command line tools from apple downloads (Xcode 4 said its already installed though). But now there is a new problem, I dont have gcc-4.2 anymore :( So this is what I see when I do easy_install

`unable to execute /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1`

I googled and found that Lion/XCode 4.2+ doesn't support gcc-4.2! Now what?

Comment: @rajivvishwa: See updates for how to handle that. 3 options. You are totally on the right path now though because its trying to compile with the right version.

Comment: I followed your steps and it worked. I've updated the post. Thanks!