# Python Imaging Library Mac OSX for Python 2.7?

Tags: python, macos, image, osx-lion, python-imaging-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to install PIL on mac os x 10.7.2 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070074/how-to-install-pil-on-mac-os-x-10-7-2-lion)

How can I get PIL for Mac OSX for Python 2.7? If there is none, is there a different library just as powerful?

Comment: Looks to me like the answer there shows how to install PIL for Python 2.7 on Lion. Would you like to explain why you think this isn't a duplicate?