# PIL loading jpg

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL to load a jpg file and display it in a label widget. At first, I got "decoding error" from python and found this post on stack overflow - [How can I install PIL on mac os x 10.7.2 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070074/how-to-install-pil-on-mac-os-x-10-7-2-lion) - and it's resolved the decoding error. However, the label doesn't display any image, just a white area. This is the code for loading image -

```
    script, file = argv 
    self.orgimg = Image.open(file)

    #Original Image
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.orgimg)
    Label(self.root, image=img).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the feeling that the image has been garbage collected. Check out this: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

If you store the image in a local variable it will be garbage collected when the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should call:

```
self.orgimg.load()
```

to actualy load the bitmap-information.

Also there's a caveat according to this [site](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pil/image-tk.html) which resemles your problem.