# draw grid lines over an image in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

How can I draw regular grid lines over a tiff image?
I want to draw regular square grids for each interval (say 100 by 100 pixels) over the image and save that with the drawings. I also need to overlay each grid id as '1','2',...at the middle of each grid box.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You will need the python imaging library (PIL) installed. (See here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL). See these answers for examples of ways to install PIL: [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070074/how-to-install-pil-on-mac-os-x-10-7-2-lion), [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil)

Right, with that installed, the following code should do what you ask for:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image

# Open image file
image = Image.open('myImage.tiff')
my_dpi=300.

# Set up figure
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(float(image.size[0])/my_dpi,float(image.size[1])/my_dpi),dpi=my_dpi)
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

# Remove whitespace from around the image
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0,right=1,bottom=0,top=1)

# Set the gridding interval: here we use the major tick interval
myInterval=100.
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=myInterval)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(loc)

# Add the grid
ax.grid(which='major', axis='both', linestyle='-')

# Add the image
ax.imshow(image)

# Find number of gridsquares in x and y direction
nx=abs(int(float(ax.get_xlim()[1]-ax.get_xlim()[0])/float(myInterval)))
ny=abs(int(float(ax.get_ylim()[1]-ax.get_ylim()[0])/float(myInterval)))

# Add some labels to the gridsquares
for j in range(ny):
    y=myInterval/2+j*myInterval
    for i in range(nx):
        x=myInterval/2.+float(i)*myInterval
        ax.text(x,y,'{:d}'.format(i+j*nx),color='w',ha='center',va='center')

# Save the figure
fig.savefig('myImageGrid.tiff',dpi=my_dpi)
```

Which, if used on the `grace_hopper.png` example file, produces the following output:

[image: Image with numbered grid]

Comment: How can u change the color of the lines in the grid?

Comment: `ax.grid(which='major', axis='both', linestyle='-', color='r')` would change them to red

Comment: I just to name you in the small project I've done taking as a basis for your code! : D  https://github.com/Criskanda/Simple-Grid-Hama-Beads

Comment: How would you modify the square size here to be say, 1cm2?

Answer (score 24):

This can be done effectively in two lines by looping over the image data at your grid intervals. Using the [canonical image](http://sipi.usc.edu/database/) from the SIPI database as an example

```
import pylab as plt

# Load the image
img = plt.imread("lena512color.tiff")

# Grid lines at these intervals (in pixels)
# dx and dy can be different
dx, dy = 100,100

# Custom (rgb) grid color
grid_color = [0,0,0]

# Modify the image to include the grid
img[:,::dy,:] = grid_color
img[::dx,:,:] = grid_color

# Show the result
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The answer by @tom may be more robust as it works with the matplotlib library. I'll leave this example up for its simplicity.

Comment: You have your dx and dy swapped in the Numpy lines.  Numpy use y,x ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just leave it here

```
def draw_grid(image, line_space=20):
    H, W = image.shape
    image[0:H:line_space] = 1
    image[:, 0:W:line_space] = 1
```

Comment: what value instead of 1 would make the grid colors black?

Comment: I made example for gray scale image, for color version you need image with 3 dimensions HxWx3