# How to print list in grid format with continuous lines?

Tags: python, grid

I´m looking for way to print (plot) one or more grid with continuous lines and within each square the values from NxN list. I found something similar in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368413/draw-grid-lines-over-an-image-in-matplotlib) thread, but in that case they are loading an image.

In my case, if I have an even number (4 in this case) of 2D lists of 5x5, I´d like to print like image below (not with "---+---" like markdown format, but with continuous lines). How can this be done. Thanks in advance.

```
list1 = [[258,658,937,560,455],[868,108,638,992,392],[649,370,825,773,751],[507,734,894,658,442],[157,831,619,614,707]]
list2 = [[130,637,502,634,901],[232,340,820,609,323],[979,549,551,116,839],[591,471,310,865,872],[969,300,321,113,218]]
list3 = [[109,908,748,165,572],[450,540,261,991,231],[327,379,965,566,932],[280,950,862,159,710],[137,450,158,441,139]]
list4 = [[987,470,155,487,851],[816,750,636,696,699],[826,264,654,114,728],[826,847,197,539,245],[915,269,821,755,552]]
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the answer you linked not useful to you? Seems like you just need to not load the image to obtain the result you want.

Comment: because that implies that I need to do something like save multiple images but previously find a way to arrange the elements of the lists in correct way, save it as image and then load each image to match the procedure in that thread. I think could be a a direct way

Comment: Check this code, it's not working but maybe someone can fix it. https://pastebin.com/aU8VC8va read the NOTE

Answer (score 0):

As you didnt share the source code you tried, it was a bit hard for me to provide you a solution. However I come up with the solution and it is working for me. You need to adjust cmap value for your desired color theme.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


list1 = [[258, 658, 937, 560, 455], [868, 108, 638, 992, 392], [649, 370, 825, 773, 751], [507, 734, 894, 658, 442],
         [157, 831, 619, 614, 707]]
list2 = [[130, 637, 502, 634, 901], [232, 340, 820, 609, 323], [979, 549, 551, 116, 839], [591, 471, 310, 865, 872],
         [969, 300, 321, 113, 218]]
list3 = [[109, 908, 748, 165, 572], [450, 540, 261, 991, 231], [327, 379, 965, 566, 932], [280, 950, 862, 159, 710],
         [137, 450, 158, 441, 139]]
list4 = [[987, 470, 155, 487, 851], [816, 750, 636, 696, 699], [826, 264, 654, 114, 728], [826, 847, 197, 539, 245],
         [915, 269, 821, 755, 552]]


lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)


fill_color = 'white'
border_color = 'lightgreen'


border_width = 3  #
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        ax = axs[i, j]
        lst = lists[i * 2 + j]


        bg = np.ones((len(lst), len(lst[0]), 3))

        ax.imshow(bg, aspect='auto')  # White fill


        for x in range(len(lst)):
            for y in range(len(lst[0])):
                ax.text(y, x, str(lst[x][y]), va='center', ha='center', color='black', fontsize=8)

        for x in range(len(lst)):
            for y in range(len(lst[0])):
                ax.add_patch(
                    plt.Rectangle((y - 0.5, x - 0.5), 1, 1, color=border_color, fill=False, linewidth=border_width))


        ax.axis('off')


plt.tight_layout()


plt.show()
```

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: `(not with "---+---" like markdown format, but with continuous lines).`

Comment: Option -1
https://ibb.co/5k061kt
Option -2 
https://ibb.co/tY2Gzm1
@Daviid please let me know which one you preferred.

Comment: I'm not the asker, but they specified continuous lines, and going by the linked answer they want to use matplotlib, not actually print to terminal.

Comment: @Daviid  I have modied the answer. I hope it will work now.

Comment: Yes and no, assuming the asker expects tha same output as in the image he posted, the colors would need to go away. If you check my last comment to his question I did this too but the problem is  drawing the grid correctly, maybe you can fix that?

Comment: @Daviid , I have finally fix it . Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you both for the help. Where do you test it? I've tried in Spyder and I don't see the output.

Comment: @RasecMalkic I used PyCharm so I can easily see the output.

Comment: @MahboobNur I've tried in Jupyter lab and is not showing your output. Weird since it shows the output for the script in thread I linked.