# PIL install - Partial JPEG support

Tags: python, macos, jpeg, python-imaging-library

Trying to use PIL for an image plotting script on Mac OS X.

Installed all the required libraries, ran 'python setup.py build_ext -i' to test and JPEG is showing as 'support available':

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
> PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
> version       1.1.7
> platform      darwin 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
>               [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
> --- TKINTER support available
> --- JPEG support available
> --- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
> --- FREETYPE2 support available
> --- LITTLECMS support available
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

However, running 'python selftest.py', though, shows as 'unsupported':

```
PIL 1.1.7 TEST SUMMARY 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from ./PIL
Binary modules loaded from ./PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok
--- TKINTER support ok
*** JPEG support not installed
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok
--- FREETYPE2 support ok
--- LITTLECMS support ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Running selftest:
*****************************************************************
Failure in example:
try:
 _info(Image.open(os.path.join(ROOT, "Images/lena.jpg")))
except IOError, v:
 print v
from line #24 of selftest.testimage
Expected: ('JPEG', 'RGB', (128, 128))
Got: decoder jpeg not available
1 items had failures:
   1 of  57 in selftest.testimage
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
*** 1 tests of 57 failed.
```

Reinstalling libjpeg and pil did not have any effect.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using PIL instead of the much more up to date [`Pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? I'd highly recommend it...

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get this to work: https://github.com/snowdonjames/LatitudeHistoryPlotter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to install PIL on mac os x 10.7.2 Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070074/how-to-install-pil-on-mac-os-x-10-7-2-lion)

Comment: @jBender I expect https://github.com/snowdonjames/LatitudeHistoryPlotter should also work with Pillow.