# getting django-simple-captcha to work

Tags: python, django, captcha, recaptcha

i am trying to get the simple captcha to work with my django.

After following the four steps:

I ran `python manage.py test captcha.`

It gave me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/Permissions/captcha/tests/__init__.py", line 26, in testImages
    response = self.client.get(reverse('captcha-image', kwargs=dict(key=key)))
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 439, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 244, in get
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/Permissions/captcha/views.py", line 27, in captcha_image
    font = ImageFont.truetype(settings.CAPTCHA_FONT_PATH, settings.CAPTCHA_FONT_SIZE)
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 218, in truetype
    return FreeTypeFont(filename, size, index, encoding)
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.font = core.getfont(file, size, index, encoding)
  File "/Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    raise ImportError("The _imagingft C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

But i actually have installed pil.

I typed sudo pip install pil, it gives me this:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pil in /Users/cnnlakshmen_2000/Projects/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
Cleaning up...
```

Not sure where my error is... Need some guidance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [_imagingft module not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011705/python-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed)

PIL has a number of optional libs (FreeType, Jpeg etc) if those libraries are missing then certain functionality in PIL will not be available.