# Font Error with Python's PIL module

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When trying to run a script with Python 2.7 on Windows, using the kivy framework, the following error is generated:

```
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "myApp.py", line 775, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 600, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 454, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_pygame.py", line 325, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_pygame.py", line 231, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 294, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 370, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 481, in _process_events
     if event.tick(self._last_tick) is False:
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 280, in tick
     ret = callback(self._dt)
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\label.py", line 200, in texture_update
     self._label.refresh()
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\__init__.py", line 413, in refresh
     sz = self.render()
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\__init__.py", line 252, in render
     lw, lh = get_extents(line)
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 33, in get_extents
     font = self._select_font()
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 27, in _select_font
     font = ImageFont.truetype(fontname, fontsize)
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 218, in truetype
     return FreeTypeFont(filename, size, index, encoding)
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 134, in __init__
     self.font = core.getfont(file, size, index, encoding)
   File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 34, in __getattr__
     raise ImportError("The _imagingft C module is not installed")
 ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

This error seems to be generated by the PIL module. I've tried installing the module with `easy_install`, and I've tried the pre-compiled executable from [here](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/); neither option helps. Any other suggestions on how to fix the issue? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: The \_imagingft C module is not installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011705/python-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed)

Comment: @Mark Hildreth - Most of the solutions in the thread to which you've pointed address the problem in linux. As stated, I've already tried the windows solution (installing from an executable) posted in that thread, and it did not help.

Comment: The question and selected answer referred to Windows. Did you download and install  [pillow](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow) as the answer and comments suggested?

Comment: It seems to be resolved with Pillow, but I'm a bit reluctant to settle on this as a solution, as I'm not sure if using this module over the original PIL variant would break some other functionality.