# Why is the Django-Simple-Captcha image not showing up?

Tags: django, captcha

I'm trying to add a Django-Simple-Captcha image to my application's login screen.

This is what I have added at the top of my forms.py file:

```
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField
```

This is what I have added to the registration form:

```
captcha = CaptchaField(
    label="What does this say?",
    required=True,
)
```

This is what I added to my site's url.py file:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        '', 
        url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')), 
    )

I have also added "captcha" to my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

However, when I load the page, I see that the Captcha image is a broken link: http://predictstat.com/accounts/register/. The server shows this on the console:

```
[23/Dec/2013 16:30:47] "GET /captcha/image/56edd656ba57a2a3e71571373e1a59c564e3d592/ HTTP/1.1" 500 72336
```

However, there is no such directory "captcha" under the directory for my application. So where is it trying to look for this image? And why doesn't it exist?

Comment: I'm currently working in the same issue. Fun fact: if you use html inspector (such as Firebug or Chrome tools) and change the image url to `/captcha/static/image/.../` it is shown.
Now I'm trying to figure out how to transform this url or make some kind of collectstatic.

Answer (score 4):

On closer inspection, I found the issue was this:

Exception Value: The _imagingft C module is not installed.

Details how to solve this issue can be found here: [Python: The _imagingft C module is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011705/python-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create any `captcha` directories.

The problem is that you did not update your `urls.py` as mensioned in the [documentation](https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#installation):

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
)
```

Another problem could be that you did not run `syncdb`:

```
./manage.py syncdb
./manage.py migrate   # If you use migrations
```

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention it, I did update my urls.py:

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
)

Comment: You get error when accessing ``/catcha/img/`` url, try to find out what kind of error it is. Did you run ``syncdb`` and ran migrations (if you use them)?

Comment: Yes. Synchdb has been run. There is no error accessing captcha/image/. The image simply doesn't show up. But I don't think that it really expects that directory to be there anyway. (In another working django-captcha application I have, it isn't there) So I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

The same was happening in my application and I manage to make a **very** strange workaround ([XGH](http://www.carlostristacci.com.br/blog/extreme-go-horse-xgh/) alert) usising two slashes in django-simple-captcha 0.4.4

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^captcha//', include('captcha.urls')),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may has something with the conflict of globally and virtureenv environment,may be there is another app which contains the name `captcha`.