# Django-simple-captcha image is broken on page. Why?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to add a Django-Simple-Captcha image to my application's login screen.

This is what I have added at the top of my forms.py file:

```
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField
```

This is what I have added to the registration form:

```
captcha = CaptchaField(
    label="What does this say?",
    required=True,
)
```

This is what I added to my site's url.py file:
    urlpatterns = patterns(
        '', 
        url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')), 
    )

I have also added "captcha" to my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

However, when I load the page, I see that the Captcha image is a broken link: http://predictstat.com/accounts/register/. The server shows this on the console:

```
[23/Dec/2013 16:30:47] "GET /captcha/image/56edd656ba57a2a3e71571373e1a59c564e3d592/ HTTP/1.1" 500 72336
```

However, there is no such directory "captcha" under the directory for my application. So where is it trying to look for this image? And why doesn't it exist?

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome dev-tools or Firebug to view your server response. You are getting 500 status (server-error) because of this:

```
ImportError at /captcha/image/eeefc1bf784d38c4eecbcd61e2e3d42a28ea6792/
The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

This error occurs if your PIL module compiled without freetype library. Fix that and your error will disappear.

Comment: Thanks. I just installed the libfreetype6-dev and then installed PIL. 
(See: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8106990)

But the result is the same: http://predictstat.com/accounts/register/

I am setting up Chrome dev-tools now.

Comment: Are you sure that your PIL is now support libfreetype? It should was in installation-log. Also, do you restart your webserver?

Comment: Yes, I am re-starting the web server.
I'm following the instructions in the last comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011705/python-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed

Yet still it says "JPEG support not available"

Comment: Try to install PIL from source: wget http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz
tar xvf Imaginig-1.1.7.tar.gz. And in setup.py point JPEG_ROOT variable to you libjpeg installation.

Comment: Follow up, cleaner question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753607/while-upgrading-python-imaging-library-pil-it-tells-me-jpeg-support-not-avai