# Python 3 "The _imagingft C module is not installed"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I want to use `django-simple-captcha` in my web site. I went through installation guide in official site but captcha image doesn't load in borrowser and this error appears in console: `500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`

Then I ran the "python3 manage.py test captcha" command in termianl (I'm working on mint 15) and get this error: `ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed`

What's the reason? ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011705/python-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed) solution didn't work for me )

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011705/python-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed

Comment: Does a re-install of Pillow indeed show freetype support to be available at the setup summary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the original `pil` package is not yet compatible with python3,
So instead use `pillow` a fork of pil

**Warning PIL and Pillow currently cannot co-exist in the same environment. If you want to use Pillow, please remove PIL first.**

first uninstall and remove your old PIL directory (if it exists)

```
sudo pip uninstall pil
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/PIL
```

install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

now install pillow

```
pip install Pillow
```

make sure u have installed pillow in your `/usr/local/lib/python[VERSION]/dist-packages/`
if it is successfully installed you should see 2 directories like
**Pillow-2.4.0-py3.2.egg-info**
and **PIL**

[see here](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) for more details and other platforms

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem of trying to start mintinstall in Mint 17. The error I had was the same:

"ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed"

After uninstalling pil and renaming its directory and installing Pillow, mintinstall could be started again.

For me, using mintinstall is important because it allows me to install packages from Mint repositories from within security levels 1,2,3.

apt-get / synaptic / aptitude, instead, would install packages regardless of the Mint security level, thus installing potentially unwanted/unsafe packages from Mint levels 4,5

Regards