# Django 1.5 "The _imagingft C module is not installed"

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, virtualenv

I'm presenting an error with the `PIL` module from Django

This is the traceback:

```
ImportError at /captcha/image/693b44b881c73846dce71a6e81460b642f76de9d/
The _imagingft C module is not installed
Request Method: GET
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:9001/captcha/image/693b44b881c73846dce71a6e81460b642f76de9d/
Django Version: 1.5.7
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
The _imagingft C module is not installed
Exception Location: F:\autanacenditel\django1.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py in __getattr__, line 34
Python Executable:  F:\autanacenditel\django1.5\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\kristian\\autana\\recaudacion',
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
'F:\\autanacenditel\\django1.5\\DLLs',
'F:\\autanacenditel\\django1.5\\lib',
'F:\\autanacenditel\\django1.5\\lib\\plat-win',
'F:\\autanacenditel\\django1.5\\lib\\lib-tk',
'F:\\autanacenditel\\django1.5\\Scripts',
'C:\\Python27\\Lib',
'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk',
'F:\\autanacenditel\\django1.5',
'F:\\autanacenditel\\django1.5\\lib\\site-packages',
'F:\\autanacenditel\\django1.5\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL']
```

My `pip freeze`

```
(django1.5) C:\Users\kristian\autana\comun>pip freeze
Django==1.5.7
Geraldo==0.4.17
PIL==1.1.7
South==0.8.4
amqp==1.4.5
anyjson==0.3.3
argparse==1.2.1
billiard==3.3.0.17
celery==3.1.11
django-braces==1.4.0
django-celery==3.0.11
django-debug-toolbar==1.1
django-extensions==1.3.7
django-floppyforms==1.1.1
django-simple-captcha==0.3.0
django-storages==1.1.6
djangorestframework==2.1.16
html5lib==0.95
kombu==3.0.15
pisa==3.0.33
psycopg2==2.5.2
python-dateutil==2.2
pytz==2014.2
reportlab==2.7
requests==1.1.0
simplejson==3.4.0
six==1.6.1
sqlparse==0.1.11
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I don't know why is this happening, I've looked for some solution here on SO, but with no luck, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Solved! I just needed to use `easy_install PIL` instead of `pip install PIL`, easy_install automatically finds the binary with all libraries in it, which is where pip fails, at least on windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: The \_imagingft C module is not installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011705/python-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed)

Comment: Yeah, but will it work on virtualenv?

Comment: You see without apt-get on a windows 7 system, i just have pip, and i can't install most of these libraries, for example libjpeg-dev, so i don't know if that answer can be effective?