# ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed

Tags: python, django, captcha

I use django-simple-captcha in django.

Command: ./manage.py test apatcha shows the error "ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed"

I already install the package in the order below:

```
yum install freetype-devel libjpeg-devel libpng-devel
pip uninstall Pillow
pip uninstall Pillow-PIL
pip install Pillow
pip install Pillow-PIL
```

But it still doesn't work.
Where am I wrong?

System:CentOS 6.5

[Python: The _imagingft C module is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011705/python-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed)

The link above doesn't solve my problem, otherwise I won't be here.
Finally, I solve my problem by download the tar.gz file from official website and install it manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: The \_imagingft C module is not installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011705/python-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed)

Comment: Did you try searching for an answer? A simple google search would lead to your solution.

Answer (score 3):

pip uninstall PIL - and -
pip install pillow

for windows these 2 commands worked for me

Comment: worked for me, I uninstalled both and then installed pillow ONLY

Answer (score 1):

[Python: The _imagingft C module is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011705/python-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed)

The link above doesn't solve my problem, otherwise I won't be here. Finally, I solve my problem by download the tar.gz file from official website and install it manually.

By the way, should I always paste the hot links which didn't solve my problem to prove I did googled before I ask?