# centos7.6 python3.8.8 ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, centos7

```py
0|Yunzai-Bot  |   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/py-plugin-FB7jtJE--py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 976, in truetype
0|Yunzai-Bot  |     return freetype(font)
0|Yunzai-Bot  |   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/py-plugin-FB7jtJE--py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 973, in freetype
0|Yunzai-Bot  |     return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
0|Yunzai-Bot  |   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/py-plugin-FB7jtJE--py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 221, in __init__
0|Yunzai-Bot  |     if core.HAVE_RAQM:
0|Yunzai-Bot  |   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/py-plugin-FB7jtJE--py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 58, in __getattr__
0|Yunzai-Bot  |     raise ImportError("The _imagingft C module is not installed")
0|Yunzai-Bot  | ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

I have tried all answers I have found and recompiled python 4 times, but it can't work. _imagingft.so is in PIL but can't be imported properly, what should I do

Comment: Are you missing libfreetype? See here for CentOS instructions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16510480/530160

Comment: @NickODell I have already installed these packages, but that doesn't help